# Xcode - Manually load a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

What I am asking may be impossible and sound weird, but here it goes.

Here is similar to what I want to achieve:

A user opens the app for the first time, there are two tab bars, in the first one (he has not tapped the second one yet) he presses a button that should initiate a progress view and text view changes and other view changes EVEN THOUGH the user has not loaded the other view controller by clicking the second tab bar.

So, is there a way to generally load a view controller before the user manually loads it himself, I know calling `viewDidLoad` manually will not help, any suggestions? Pretty confusing, it is like modifying a view but the controller has not loaded yet...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes in the other view controller and then let the controller configure its own view when it does its natural loading.

Comment: Right, why didnt I think of that, just set the values and once the view loads auto set the view changes.... thanks!

Comment: Being too close to something to see it clearly never stops happening.  :-)